# Exclude a program from the Open With list for a specific file extension

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry, file-types

When I upload a file of a certain type with a Browse... button (`<input type="file">`) on a web page, the browser I'm using gets added to that file type's open with list. For example, if I do this:

[image]

I get this:

[image]

It also does that if I do the same thing with another browser, so it isn't specific to Chrome. For example, if I upload the zip file using Firefox, it will add Firefox to that list.

The problem is that if I try to open a zip file in a browser just like that by right-clicking on the zip file and doing Open with -> (name of browser), all it will do is download the zip file, which is useless since the zip file is already on my hard drive. For this reason, I don't want any browser showing up in the open with list for zip files (and there are also other file extensions such as docx that browsers can't open, so I don't want any browsers in their open with lists either).

I know that I can remove the browser from that list by going to the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.zip\OpenWithList` and removing the value corresponding to the browser, but if I do that and then upload another zip file using a browser, it will show up again. This means that each time I upload a file of a type that a browser can't open, I have to manually remove it through the registry, which is annoying.

So my question is, is there any way to tell Windows explicitly *not* to show a certain program in a certain file extension's open with list? Maybe add something to the registry? I've searched the web, but haven't found anything.

Comment: *Perhaps* the better question is why is the browser getting automatically added to the Open With list? I've uploaded my weight in Bitcoin of files and have never had this happen.